# Completely delete references to previous Vue component when I navigate away

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

I have a Vue component `/foo` that listens to `scroll` and `resize` events:

```
export default {
    name: 'foo',
    mounted() {
        window.onresize = function (event) {
            //doing stuff
            console.log('doing onresize stuff');
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
            //doing stuff
            console.log('doing scroll stuff');
        });
...
```

Which works correctly. However, when I use `VueRouter` and signout and away from `/foo` to another component `/bar` my console is still being filled with `scroll` and `resize` events when I scroll and resize on the new `/bar` component:

```
doing scroll stuff
doing onresize stuff
doing scroll stuff
doing scroll stuff
doing scroll stuff
```

How can I completely stop all references and delete(?) the previous page (`/foo`) from memory so that this does not happen?

Comment: You need to remove the event listeners in the `beforeDestroy` or `destroyed` hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `removeEventListener`

```js
const handler = (event) => console.log(event)

export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handler)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler)
  }
}
```

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) has more examples.

If you're listening to events on DOM, you can use Vue's `v-on` or `@` syntax, e.g. `@click`. Vue will handle the event listeners for you in this case.